# LaTeX workshop compiler doesn't terminate after successfully generating output .pdf

Tags: luatex, compiling, vscode, latex-workshop

When I try to compile my .tex document via LaTeX workshop, the process successfully generates a .pdf document, but fails to stop. The compiler outputs `Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 5176 bytes).` and the .pdf document looks right. However, the status bar on the lower left of the VSCode window ("↻ lualatex") indicates that the build process is still ongoing. Pressing "Terminate current compilation" fails to stop the process.

The tool I use to run the build process is defined as

```
{
    "name": "lualatex",
    "command": "lualatex",
    "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-pdf",
        "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
        "--shell-escape",
        "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
},
```

Removing any arguments doesn't seem to solve the issue.

The weird thing is that compiling the file via terminal using `lualatex main.tex --shell-escape -pdf` works perfectly well—the output document is produced and the compiler successfully terminates.

The minimal (non-)working example of the `main.tex` is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

% This package seems to be the culprit
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}

\begin{document}
\gabcsnippet{(c4)}
\end{document}
```

It seems that the *gregoriotex* package is involved in the issue, since the issue disapears if I remove it and any associated commands. However, it's not like it is causing the build to fail—the output .pdf is successfully generated! The issue is that for whatever reason the build fails to terminate after producing output.

I would be grateful for any help solving this issue!

Comment: can you check using your operating system process list tool whether something is still running in the background (gregorio executable for example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems there is nothing unusual still running in the background. I couldn't find a process related to gregorio

Comment: One additional thing I noticed is that the issue only arises when I make changes to lines involving gregoriotex commands. LaTeX workshop builds just fine if after restarting VSCode I've only made non-gregoriotex changes to the document. (Still, compiling via terminal works either way)